# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment, python with json files

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The following is my code

```
import json
with open('johns.json', 'r') as q:
    l = q.read()
    data = json.loads(l)
    data['john'] = '{}'
    data['john']['user'] = 'hey'
```

The following is the json file

```
{}
```

Every time I run my code I get the error

```
    data['john']['user'] = 'hey'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a way to fix this and make data['john']['user'] equal hey?

Comment: Why did you put quotes around `{}`? That makes a string, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. First of all, you can use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`. The former is used to directly get the data from a json file.

Then, you are assigning to `data['john']` a string, instead of an actual dictionary.

```
import json
with open('johns.json', 'r') as q:
    data = json.load(q)
    data['john'] = {}
    data['john']['user'] = 'hey'
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't put quotes around `{}`, that creates a string instead of a dictionary.

You can also fill in the contents in the same assignment:

```
data['john'] = {"user": "hey"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It must read

```
data['john'] = dict()
# or data['john'] = {}
```

Otherwise, `data["john"]` is a string, namely `{}`.

Comment: They just need to remove the quotes around `{}`, it's not necessary to call the function.

Comment: @Barmar: I guess it's equally true, isn't it?

Comment: It's more idiomatic I think.

Comment: @Barmar: Added an alternative. Thanks for spotting it.